# ruby on rails xml builder question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xml-builder

Anybody know how to produce an xml element like this in rails using xml Builder?
`<image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>`

`xml.image :loc http://example.com/image.jpg`
[Is supposed to work](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, but the correct syntax is:

```
xml.image :loc, "http://example.com/image.jpg"
```